# Animate Toolbar Logo / Title changes when using with ViewPager Fragments

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-toolbar

I am using ViewPager to host two fragments in my main activity. One fragment is intended to show app logo and other one just title on the Toolbar. I am able to do that without any issue.

However, I want to animate these changes when I swipe from one fragment to another using swipe on ViewPager, like Fade out the logo and fade in the title.

Any clue or idea how can I do it.

Ok, as per Amir's suggestion I tried it using the below layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:alpha="1"
        >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo_image"
        android:alpha="1"
       />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toolbar_log_container"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_info_container"
        >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_profile_pic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/one"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/value_12"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_user_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextInfoName"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/toolbar_profile_pic"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/toolbar_profile_pic"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/value_8"
        />
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_user_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextInfoWork"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_user_name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/toolbar_profile_pic"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/toolbar_profile_pic"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/toolbar_profile_pic"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And it works ! But what if I would have to do it as per scroll position of the ViewPager. I tried placing the animation in

```
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}
```

part of the code, but the animation runs uncontrollably, since this callback is called everytime once the scroll is started, irrespective of it is actually scrolled or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, here's what I did to achieve the desired effect:

```java
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            private float prevPosition = 0.0f;
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                ///hold current position
                if(prevPosition == 0) {
                    prevPosition = positionOffset;
                    return;
                }
                
                ///check if prev position is equal to current one, avoid multiple calls
                if(prevPosition == positionOffset) {
                    return;
                }
                
                /// zero position check
                if(prevPosition >= 0.9) {
                    if(positionOffset == 0.0f) {
                        Logger.log_error("Do not hide infoHolder");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                //update previous position
                prevPosition = positionOffset;
                
                ///animate title text and logoholder accordingly
                logoHolder.animate().translationX(logoHolder.getWidth() -positionOffset * logoHolder.getWidth()) .alpha(positionOffset).setDuration(0).start();
                mTitleText.animate().translationX(- positionOffset * mTitleText.getWidth()).alpha(1.0f - logoHolder.getAlpha()).setDuration(0).start();

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
});
```

The above code resulted in a smooth transition b/w Logo and title text when fragments are scrolled inside viewpager.

Posting the answer hoping this may help someone else.

Thanks Amir for the guidance.

Comment: With boolean flag check that animation not running previously it's make your scrolled laggy.

Answer (score 1):

For Animating `Toolbar` you should define your own `Toolbar` something like [this](https://github.com/AmirHadifar/Flashcard/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/toolbar_default.xml) and for Animating elements of `Toolbar` in your **MainActivity** you can use something like following code:

```
 getLeftIcon().animate()
                .translationY(0)
                .setDuration(300)
                .setStartDelay(300);
        getAppLogo().animate()
                .translationY(0)
                .setDuration(300)
                .setStartDelay(400);
```

and for changing title due to `ViewPager` position just define listener for your `ViewPager` :

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // Change your title here 
    }
});
```

Animation part of code available [here](https://github.com/AmirHadifar/Flashcard/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/hadifar/dope/ui/activity/BaseDrawerActivity.java).

Comment: Thanks Amir. I will try the solution and will update!

Comment: @trivalent instead of **onPageScrolled** put your code in **onPageSelected** and it's happen just when page scrolled completely.

Comment: if you want to start animation from specific of position of scrolled (e.g 90% scrolled, put you code in **onPageScrolled** and handle it with some conditions) there are lot's of code out there about this issue too.

Comment: if you have some reference, please share. I am doing the same as you suggested. Lets see...

Comment: @trivalent **positionOffset** attribute `Value from [0, 1) indicating the offset from the page at position.`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageScrolled(int, float, int)